# Wifi Stopped Working in Ubuntu 20.04 After Restart

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, network-manager

A few days ago, after I restarted my laptop and wifi icon isn't even showing anymore. I didn't have any problems with my wifi connection before. When looking for answers I found that these information were useful to figure out what could be wrong:

ifconfig

```
enp7s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f4:8e:38:e5:fc:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1435  bytes 131490 (131.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1435  bytes 131490 (131.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::f27b:2ce2:8d8d:5d59  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4a:e3:5f:89:e8:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 57300  bytes 75633797 (75.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32733  bytes 5043522 (5.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.123.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.123.255
        ether 52:54:00:1f:f9:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
  '*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: f4:8e:38:e5:fc:44
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:1f:f9:13
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.123.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:1f:f9:13
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@2:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 4a:e3:5f:89:e8:2f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.44 link=yes multicast=yes´
```

rfkill list all

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When i type `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` nothing happens.

I am a beginner on Linux, know nothing about code, really need my Wifi and laptop working properly for my job and study and also very grateful for any help I can get.

Edited:

Figured out that after my laptop suspends, it seems to reconnect my wifi. Well, not only that, when I turn it off and on, looks like i don't even have a wi-fi hardware, but after closing and opening my notebook, wifi shows up again, connects, I even get different responses on terminal.

I could type on terminal something that i don't remember, but copied the response:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 94:53:30:aa:f5:bf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7100000-f717ffff memory:f7180000-f718ffff

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Vostro 3470 [1028:020e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

That's it, still don't know what the problem is, but have a partial solution.

Edited again:

Solved after cleaning the laptop and changing thermal paste.

Comment: How happened that you have a 5.8 kernel on Ubuntu 20.04? Did you enable the `proposed` repo? Boot with a 5.4 kernel and check.

Comment: One of the solutions i looked for was to upgrade the kernel. The problem started with the 5.4. Edited: one of my other tries was to upgrade ubuntu, now it is Ubuntu 20.10. Dont't know what it is to open the `proposed` repo

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxB6asfgKOc)):

1. `sudo lshw -class network`

We're interested in the product number: [product number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z6Ou.png)

2. `cd /etc/pm/sleep.d`
3. `sudo touch config`
4. `sudo gedit config`

Add this line to the config file (don't forget to use your own product number):

```
SUSPEND_MODULES= "RTL8723AE"
```

5.`echo "options RTL8723AE fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/RTL8723AE.conf` (don't forget to use your own product number)

6. Reboot

Comment: This solution is for a specific Realtek device.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually, I just had to clean my notebook.